Can't access backend
I have lost access to wp-admin after inputting multilingual material to a WP/LearnDash site. (message: “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.”)
I have tried dozens of tweaks to gain access to the backend but have had no success.
An IT guy suggested cleaning the database from illegal/invalid characters that probably are causing this problem.
Are there any suggestions for a PHP script that I could run and fix the database?
Thank you in advance.

Do you think it's the user that lost access or that the site is corrupt?  Does the rest of the site work?  Are there other users that can still login?
